# Problems with public and private

Tags: c++, class, private, public

I just started programming so don't be too harsh if I'm saying something stupid right now...
What I'm trying to make in C++ is a class that represents a graph. Each graph has its list of nodes, which is are its own class. The problem is that I want to make some members of the class "node" private, so they won't be accessible from for instance the main function, however, I want to make them accessible inside the graph class. The class node itself should be accessible though outside the class graph. So is this possible?

Comment: make the graph class friend of the node class.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that you have a class `Node` for your nodes and a class `Graph` for your graphs.
You could make `Graph` class `friend` of class `Node` like the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
  friend class Graph;
  //...
  std::size_t id;
  public:
  Node(std::size_t const _id) : id(_id) {}
  //...
};

class Graph {
 //...
 public:
 Graph(Node const &node) { std::cout << "Look! I can access input node its id is " << node.id << std::endl; }
 //...
};

int main() {
  Node n(1);
  Graph G(n);
}
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a95adad4fd7bdf16)